# fmap on functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement fmap for functions and can't quite figure out how to the "lift" applies to a function as compared to how all the documentation refers to simple kinds like `Maybe`

The type of the function I want to implement is

```
fmapFunction :: (a -> b) -> (e -> a) -> (e -> b)
```

Any ideas how I should go about this?

Comment: You could also [cheat](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=(a+-%3E+b)+-%3E+(e+-%3E+a)+-%3E+(e+-%3E+b)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It may be easier to see if you flip the types around:

```
(e -> a) -> (a -> b) -> (e -> b)
```

We can turn an `e` into an `a`, and an `a` into a `b`. So how can we turn an `e` into a `b`?

Don't focus too much on "lifting"; with `Functor` instances, the best way to discover the implementation is simply to follow the type.